# Creating a 'new company' if a company isn't found when adding it to work experience

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to work out the logic here...

I have a profile model which includes work experience. If the user adds a unique salon(company) I'd like to create a new company using the salon(company) schema.

The use case for this is to use the salon model to create separate pages on the front-end for the salons.

```
const ProfileSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'user'
  },
...
  experience: [
    {
      jobTitle: {
        type: String,
      },
      jobRole: {
        type: String,
      }
      jobSalon: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'salon'
      },
      jobFrom: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
      },
      jobTo: {
        type: Date
      },
      jobCurrent: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },
      jobDescription: {
        type: String
      }
    }
  ]
...
});
```

**The salon schema**

```
const SalonSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        salonCompany: {
                type: String,
                required: true
        },
        salonLocation: {
                type: String,
                required: true
        }
})
```

**API add experience route**

```
// @route   PUT api/profile/experience
// @desc    Add profile experience
// @access  Private

router.put('/experience', [auth, [
    check('jobRole', 'Role is required').not().notEmpty(),
    check('jobFrom', 'Start date is required').not().notEmpty()
]], async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req)
        if(!errors.isEmpty()){
            return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array})
        }

    const {
        jobTitle,
        jobRole,
        jobSalon,
        jobLocation,
        jobFrom,
        jobTo,
        jobCurrent,
        jobDescription
    } = req.body

    const newExp = {
        jobTitle,
        jobRole,
        jobSalon,
        jobLocation,
        jobFrom,
        jobTo,
        jobCurrent,
        jobDescription
    }

    try {
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })

        profile.experience.unshift(newExp)

        await profile.save()
        
        res.json(profile)

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
        res.status(500).send('Server error')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the most elegant, or appropriate solution, but seems to be working.

After getting the req.body from the experience, I'm running a check to to see if the salon exists in the Salon database, if it does, then I continue, if it doesn't it creates a new one. Then continues to add the experience

```
const existingSalon = await Salon.findOne({ salonCompany: jobSalon })

        if(!existingSalon){
            // if no salon found
            // create a new instance of salon
            newSalon = new Salon({
                salonCompany: req.body.jobSalon
            })
            // save the new salon in the database
            await newSalon.save()
            const jobSalon = newSalon
        }  else {
            // if it does exist use it 
            const jobSalon = existingSalon
        }
```

And in the context of the route: (thinking I should refactor the above as middleware)

```
// @route   PUT api/profile/experience
// @desc    Add profile experience
// @access  Private

router.put('/experience', [auth, [
    check('jobRole', 'Role is required').not().notEmpty(),
    check('jobFrom', 'Start date is required').not().notEmpty()
]], async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req)
        if(!errors.isEmpty()){
            return res.status(400).json({errors: errors.array})
        }

    const {
        jobTitle,
        jobRole,
        jobSalon,
        jobLocation,
        jobFrom,
        jobTo,
        jobCurrent,
        jobDescription
    } = req.body

    const existingSalon = await Salon.findOne({ salonCompany: jobSalon })

        if(!existingSalon){
            // if no salon found
            // create a new instance of salon
            newSalon = new Salon({
                salonCompany: req.body.jobSalon
            })
            // save the new salon in the database
            await newSalon.save()
            const jobSalon = newSalon
        }  else {
            // if it does exist use it 
            const jobSalon = existingSalon
        }

    const newExp = {
        jobTitle,
        jobRole,
        jobSalon,
        jobLocation,
        jobFrom,
        jobTo,
        jobCurrent,
        jobDescription
    }

    try {
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id })

        profile.experience.unshift(newExp)

        await profile.save()
        
        res.json(profile)

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message)
        res.status(500).send('Server error')
    }
})
```